# How to implement INotifyPropertyChanged with LINQ-To-Entity objects

Tags: wpf, linq-to-entities, binding

I am using a LINQ-to-Entity Model attached to my database.  I can do normal binding using LINQ with no problems, example:

```
Dim db As New myEntityModel
dim myCustomers As New Customers

myCustomers=db.Customers.ToList

dim myItemSource = From c in myCustomers
                   Select c   

myComboBox.ItemsSource = myItemSource
```

Easy!  But my question is how do I implement INotifyPropertyChanged so that controls that I bind to are automatically updated whenever the data source changes?

Comment: Do you mean Entity Framework? Or Linq to Sql? Did you try to use POCO?

Comment: I am using Entity Framework - LINQ to Entities.  I'm not sure what POCO is, although I've seen it mentioned in my exhaustive googling around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make a whole lot of sense :-)

First:

```
dim myItemSource = From c in myCustomers
                   Select c
```

This is not needed ad all, you can change the last line to this: `myComboBox.ItemsSource = myCustomers`. No need for `myItemSource`. This can be further simplified to `myComboBox.ItemsSource = db.Customers.ToList`. No need for `myCustomers` either.

Second:
You want your combobox to be updated when the customers change. Then why are you not binding directly to `db.Customers` but to a static list that will never change? `db.Customers.ToList` will create a snapshot of the contents of `db.Customers`. It will not be updated, when `db.Customers` is updated.

Conclusion:
Your code should look like this:

```
Dim db As New myEntityModel
myComboBox.ItemsSource = db.Customers
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel Hilgarth. DUH! Thanks for the code simplification! Sometimes when you look for complexity you miss the simplest solution! The code looks better now, but it still doesn't work. When I run the program the ComboBox displays my customers fine, but when I change the data in the database, the customers in the ComboBox _remain unchanged_. What am I doing wrong? I am using **DisplayMemberPath=CustomerName** in my **XAML**

Comment: @Jason: Are you changing the customers directly in the database or in the entity framework? Your entity context is **not** automatically updated when someone else changes your database. You need to requery it.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Hilgarth.  I am changing directly in my database NOT just in the framework, like my question says. I need my items source in the ComboBox changed automatically whenever the database is changed.

Comment: @Jason: That's not supported. As I said, you need to manually requery the database.

Comment: @ Daniel Hilgarth If that's true then what is the whole point of the iNotifyPropertyChanged interface?